# How can I get the name of field group in CFS?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, field

In Wordpress, there is a plugin called Custom Field Suite:
https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-suite/

The problem? I can't target all fields in a specific field group. I can see that the field group is of type post, but I can't seem to target it.

The API has also no information about it:
https://mgibbs189.github.io/custom-field-suite/api.html

My ambition is to fetch all fields in a **specific** field group, instead of having to query all fields one by one.

Any chance someone has got it to work?

**Edit:**

If I do a var dump of what is there, I do not find the names of the field groups. That is the whole problem.

```
$list = CFS()->get();
print_r ($list);

Array ( [tester] => test
[location] => nomee)
```

While the name of my field group = "Hello"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create a group of fields in the CFS plugin, we technically create a custom post type called cfs

We will also create three custom fields:

1. cfs_extras - This is where the field group settings are stored
2. cfs_rules - the conditions to show the fields group, in which custom post type or taxonomy it should be shown
3. cfs_fields - additional fields of the group are stored here

If we need to find fields for a group of fields, first we have to make a query like this

```
$my_fields_group_name = 'test';

$query = get_posts( 'no_found_rows=true&fields=ids&post_type=cfs&s=' . $my_fields_group_name );

$my_fields_group_post_id = $query[0];
```

And then get the names of the fields from the custom field "cfs_fields"

```
$my_fields = get_post_meta($my_fields_group_post_id , "cfs_fields", true);

print_r($my_fields);
```

Now we have all the custom field keys and we can get the values of these fields

```
$current_post_id = get_the_id();
foreach($my_fields as $my_field) {
$custom_field_key = $my_field ['name'];

$custom_field_value = get_post_meta($current_post_id , $custom_field_key, true);
echo $custom_field_key . ' - ' . $custom_field_value;
echo '<br>';
}
```

Here is all the code combined

```
$my_fields_group_name = 'test';

$query = get_posts( 'no_found_rows=true&fields=ids&post_type=cfs&s=' . $my_fields_group_name );

$my_fields_group_post_id = $query[0];

$my_fields = get_post_meta($my_fields_group_post_id , "cfs_fields", true);

print_r($my_fields);
echo '<br>';

$current_post_id = get_the_id();

foreach($my_fields as $my_field) {

$custom_field_key = $my_field ['name'];

$custom_field_value = get_post_meta($current_post_id , $custom_field_key, true);
echo $custom_field_key . ' - ' . $custom_field_value;
echo '<br>';

}
```

**Update**
If you dont want to query each time, you can get post_id of custom post fields group

```
$my_fields_group_name = 'test';

$query = get_posts( 'no_found_rows=true&fields=ids&post_type=cfs&s=' . $my_fields_group_name );

$my_fields_group_post_id = $query[0];
```

And use this id direct in code

```
$my_id = 28;
$my_fields = get_post_meta($my_id , "cfs_fields", true);

$current_post_id = get_the_id();

foreach($my_fields as $my_field) {

$custom_field_key = $my_field ['name'];

$custom_field_value = get_post_meta($current_post_id , $custom_field_key, true);
echo $custom_field_key . ' - ' . $custom_field_value;
echo '<br>';

}
```

Comment: Awesome! This works, however: is it possible to shorten this? Like: I know exactly which field groups I need to pick up instead of query all field groups and I probably would need to do this 4 or 5 times to pick up certain field groups. Is there a more efficient / nifty way?

Comment: Try updated code

Comment: Thanks: is there a way we can give a class name per field (not field group)? I don't think CFS allows us to send classes per field, but it would be important for me. Is there a way?

Comment: Is there a way we can get rid of the <br> that is being outputted by $custom_field_value? Even if you remove the echo <br>, there is still a break that seems to come from $custom_field_value.

Comment: Any chance you can help?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're going for, if you just need to output the values of the fields -  
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "field_name", true); ?>

Field name we set manually for each field when we create a group of fields.

Comment: But you can't create a class in CFS when creating, right? Where is that option?